# GetToken failed with status code: ServiceDisabled

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Sign in to login into a app I am building to display calendars. Post Google Sign in - it also logs into Firebase where the user data is stored in the Realtime Database. While the whole app was working properly - suddenly it stopped syncing with the Google Calendar API and I get the below "Errors" in the Info. I am able to login and with new accounts just no sync - app works - no data. I have tried checking multiple issues and even reverted to old code - no diff. Firebase user data is also being displayed in the app. Can anybody please suggest an approach to solving this issue?

```
    2021-01-04 09:59:21.021 2139-4708/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: ServiceDisabled
2021-01-04 09:59:21.022 10175-10254/ W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
2021-01-04 09:59:21.022 10175-10254/ W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:286)
2021-01-04 09:59:21.022 10175-10254/ W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
2021-01-04 09:59:21.023 10175-10254/ W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
2021-01-04 09:59:21.023 10175-10254/ W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
2021-01-04 09:59:21.023 10175-10254/ W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
2021-01-04 09:59:21.023 10175-10254/ W/System.err:     at .Fragments.Home$syncWholeCalendar$1.invokeSuspend(Home.kt:298)
```

**Below is the code I use to get the user to sign in**

```
private const val TAG = "WelcomeActivity"

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
//For Google Sign In
val RC_SIGN_IN: Int = 9001
private lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
lateinit var mGoogleSignInOptions: GoogleSignInOptions
private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
private var firebaseUserID : String = ""
private lateinit var refUsers : DatabaseReference

//get data from google signin in handlesigninresult
private var googleId  = ""
private var googleFirstName = ""
private var googleLastName = ""
private var googleEmail = ""
private var googleProfilePicURL = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)
//        //For google sign in
//        configureGoogleSignIn()
//        setupUI()
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("896894788293-oe0enptjj2hltdde9isemuf89gtkb7u4.apps.googleusercontent.com")
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    google_login.setOnClickListener {
        signIn()
    }

    login_welcome.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}

private fun signIn() {
    val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task =
            GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
    }
}

private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(
            ApiException::class.java
        )
        // Signed in successfully
        googleId = account?.id ?: ""
        Log.i("Google ID", googleId)

        googleFirstName = account?.givenName ?: ""
        Log.i("Google First Name", googleFirstName)

        googleLastName = account?.familyName ?: ""
        Log.i("Google Last Name", googleLastName)

        googleEmail = account?.email ?: ""
        Log.i("Google Email", googleEmail)

        val googleIdToken: String = account?.idToken ?: ""
        Log.i("Google ID Token", googleIdToken)

        googleProfilePicURL = account?.photoUrl.toString()
        Log.i("Google Profile Pic URL", googleProfilePicURL)

        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(googleIdToken)

    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        // Sign in was unsuccessful
        Log.e(
            "failed code=", e.statusCode.toString()
        )
    }
}

private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")

                firebaseUserID = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid
                refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(
                    firebaseUserID
                )
                refUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                        if (p0.exists()) {
                            val user: Users? = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)
                            //Check if user exists in the database
                            if (user!!.getFirstName() != null) {
                                val intent = Intent(
                                    this@WelcomeActivity,
                                    IntroSplashScreen::class.java
                                )
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                            } else {
                                val usersHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                                usersHashMap["uid"] = firebaseUserID
                                usersHashMap["firstname"] = googleFirstName
                                usersHashMap["surname"] = googleLastName
                                usersHashMap["profile"] = googleProfilePicURL
                                usersHashMap["primaryEmail"] = googleEmail
                                usersHashMap["search"] =
                                    googleFirstName.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)

                                refUsers.updateChildren(usersHashMap)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                            val intent = Intent(
                                                this@WelcomeActivity,
                                                IntroSplashScreen::class.java
                                            )
                                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                            startActivity(intent)
                                            finish()
                                        }

                                    }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                })
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                // ...

            }
            // ...
        }
}

   private fun refreshIdToken() {
        // Attempt to silently refresh the GoogleSignInAccount. If the GoogleSignInAccount
        // already has a valid token this method may complete immediately.
        //
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently and get a valid
        // ID token. Cross-device single sign on will occur in this branch.
        mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn()
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                this
            ) { task -> handleSignInResult(task) }
    }


override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    //Checks if the Google IDToken has expired, if yes it refreshes by SilentSign in and generates new Firebase Token
    refreshIdToken()
    //Checks if user is logged in to firebase
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    //If logged in then sends to MainActivity
    if(firebaseUser!=null){
        startActivity(IntroSplashScreen.getLaunchIntent(this))
        finish()
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    refreshIdToken()
}
}
```

Comment: `ServiceDisabled` does what it says.

Comment: Hi Martin, ok, makes sense, but why has Sync with Calendar APi stopped working, when user is able to login (with Google) and view data from Firebase... or rather why has Service been disabled - what do I need to do to reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to create a Beta Test Program, as anybody who was not associated/listed was blocked from accessing data.